# Does Fiddler create private root certificates uniquely per machine?

Tags: security, debugging, http, proxy, fiddler

When using Fiddler, it asks for installing a root certificate which automatically decrypts SSL traffic. But also it informs that the user shouldn't install it unless it's a test system.

My understanding is because Fiddler's using the same private key in every computer an attacker can get this private key and do a real MITM and user wouldn't know because the computer is trusting Fiddler's root.

However this line in [Fiddler's website](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) contradict's with my theory of shared private keys:

> If the client computer itself previously had run Fiddler in
>   HTTPS-decryption mode, all attempts to visit HTTPS pages secured by
>   the other computer's version of Fiddler will fail with an unspecified
>   certificate problem. To resolve this, remove the Fiddler root
>   certificate that is in the client's certificate store. (The mismatched
>   root certificate causes the problem, as every Fiddler instance
>   generates its own unique root).

My question is; Why Fiddler is not creating a private key per machine basis so it would be safe. If Fiddler is already doing this, why tell users to do not install it unless it's a test system?

Just to be clear I'm talking about this warning:
[image]

Comment: @Eric, is that mean it actually safe but you just put it to make lawyers happy? Is that implemented as I wrote (different private keys in different computers?) If so we'll install it in many places without worry if not then I hope we can find a way to address it make it secure.

Comment: Every Fiddler root certificate has a unique private key on only that machine.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I recently confirmed that as well checking how the cert generated in the first place by using makecert, thanks for the clarifitcation.

Comment: What this certificate gives the person who generates it in terms of accessibility on my machine?

Answer (score 7):

**Q:** Does Fiddler create private root certificates uniquely per machine?

**A:** Yes, of course. http://www.telerik.com/blogs/faq---certificates-in-fiddler

> What’s the Risk?
>
> Many security folks are worried that, if a user configures Windows to
>   trust Fiddler’s root certificate, that user could have their traffic
>   intercepted and decrypted by any other Fiddler user. They assume that
>   Fiddler is sharing the same root certificate across all installations.
>
> Fear not! Every Fiddler root certificate is uniquely generated, per
>   user, per machine. No two Fiddler installations have the same root
>   certificate. The only way for a Fiddler user to be “spoofed” by a bad
>   guy is if that bad guy already is running code inside the user’s
>   account (which means you’d already be pwned anyway).